# audit trigger in oracle12c is compiling with error

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, audit

[refer my ER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huDHH.png)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EVA 
    AFTER INSERT ON C_EVALUATION
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    v_cid number(25);
    v_isbn number(25);
    v_cname VARCHAR2(50);
    v_tittle VARCHAR2(150);
    v_date date;
    v_location VARCHAR2(50);
    v_eva VARCHAR2(250);
    BEGIN
    v_cid:=:OLD.C_ID;
    v_isbn:=:OLD.B_ISBN;
    v_eva:=:OLD.e_desc;

    SELECT C_NAME INTO v_cname FROM C_CUSTOMER WHERE C_ID = v_cid;
    select l_date INTO v_date FROM C_LEND where c_id = v_cid;
    select B_TITTLE INTO v_tittle FROM C_BOOK WHERE B_ISBN = v_isbn;
    SELECT TOWN INTO v_location FROM COPY WHERE B_ISBN = v_isbn;

    IF :NEW.R_ID IS NULL 
    THEN       
        INSERT INTO e_audit (
        c_name,
        b_tittle,
        h_date,
        location,
        evaluation
    ) VALUES (
        v_cname,
        v_tittle,
        v_date,
        v_location,
        v_eva
    );
    END IF;
    END;
    /
```

in the book table evaluation is given, but the evaluation,rate should be given by the customer, if the customer gives the rate as null value the below trigger should work. But we are getting an error saying as statement ignored, table or view does not exist. I checked it twice or more than that but all the table name and ID are perfect. please give us the solution to sort out the error

Comment: Could SELECT TOWN INTO v_location FROM COPY WHERE B_ISBN = v_isbn; be the problem?  Everywhere else you are using x_ style prefixes, but for some reason you do not for TOWN and COPY.  Also your INSERT has location and evaluation without prefixes

Comment: Awesome Jonathan , i made a mistake on the table name. we've fixed it, thank you so much, trigger compiled without errors , but when we try to give evaluation with the null value, we are getting an error saying 'exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows','error during execution of trigger 'EVA'' so i don't know how to fix that , if u can help me to, i would be very happy

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else looks wrong here.  This is an INSERT trigger, but you are referring to :OLD.e_desc.  This is wrong.  An INSERT trigger should only refer to :NEW.  A DELETE trigger should only refer to :OLD, whilst an UPDATE trigger can refer to both :NEW and :OLD.  :OLD gives the value of the record before the change, but for INSERT there was no such record.  I think what you really want is to use :NEW.e_desc, :NEW.c_id and :NEW.b_isbn.  But I am guessing a little!

EDIT

Your diagram does not show all the fields? But what I think you need is:

```
SELECT TOWN into v_location FROM copy inner join lend 
ON lend.copyid = copy.copyid WHERE b_isbn = v_isbn 
AND lend.c_id = v_cid
```

What I am assuming here is that lend has a field copyid linking to copy.copyid and that it has a field linking to customer id. I am also assuming that copy has a field linking to b_isbn in book. According to your diagram, this must all be true, it is just that I do not know the field names.

Comment: Yes, That's correct , but even after we have done the changes , we are getting the same error saying 'fetching more than one row'.:-(

Comment: INSERT INTO c_evaluation (
    e_desc,
    b_isbn,
    c_id,
    r_id
) VALUES (
    'nice book',
    14002,
    29,
    null
)
Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "OPS$1629266.EVA", line 14
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'EVA'

Comment: can you edit your question with the revised code, so that I can check if there is anything else wrong, please?

Comment: What I suspect is wrong is that one of the SELECT INTO statements returns more than one record.  For example are you sure that c_id exists only once in C_LEND (would mean you can only borrow once??) and that b_isbn is unique in COPY.  These are suspicious!  I think you need to add to the WHERE clause to ensure only one record is found

Comment: Yeah,Actually you are correct, in my relationship one book has many copies,(each book has 2-5 copies) and that copy can be lend by customers.

Comment: so each copy has unique ID and location of the book,book_ID

Comment: In which case, I'm guessing you will probably need a join in the SELECT TOWN into v_location query, to make sure you only get the right record.  Without sight of all the table structures, though, I cannot give you a definite answer

Comment: If you have two copies in the same location, then you will need in addition SELECT DISTINCT

Comment: i have added a refer my ER link up there, there you can see my ER diagram, if u have found any problem with the structure, any solution regarding this trigger please let me know. thanks jonathan.